# How Can you add a Hidden Input Type inside an option tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

```
  function vGetUsers(elem, id) {
  var cat = $("#cat" + elem).val();
  var xstr = "";
  debugger;
  $.ajax({
  url: '/ApplicationNew/getAllUsers',
  type: 'POST',
  data: { 'Cat': cat },
  dataType: 'json',
  async: false,
  success: function (b) {
      for (x = 0; x < b.length; x++) {

      xstr = xstr + '<option value="' + b[x].UserName + '">' + b[x].FirstName + ' ' + b[x].MiddleInitial + ' ' + b[x].LastName + '</option>'(HERE IS WHERE I WANT TO PLACE THE INPUT TYPE HIDDEEN IS THIS POSIBLE?[enter image description here][1]);
                }
      localStorage.removeItem('vUsers'); //tracked0629
      localStorage.setItem('vUsers', xstr);
            }
        });
    }
```

that what happens when i put this `<input type="hidden" id="userName' + id + '" value="' + b[x].UserName + '" hidden/>` inside the option tag.

Comment: i cant put the out when i put an input type hidden in the option tag -_-

Comment: No its not possible (an `<option>` cannot have child elements). What are you trying to do with this anyway - it makes no sense)

Comment: Why putting hidden input in an option tag? Isn't that `value` attribute in `option` tag enough? No child tag elements can be added for `option` tags - they're creating list of items.

Comment: i was hoping to put an input type hidden inside it so i can get the id of that input type and pass it to another function.

Comment: The hidden input must be placed outside `option` tag - it is in your form with either `input type="hidden"` or `Html.Hidden[For]`. You can assign the hidden input value with selected `select` item using JS (`$('#hidden').val(data)`).

Comment: That makes no sense. The `value` of the option should be your ID, and the display text of the option should be your user name etc.

Comment: i get it now sorry -_- . this should be the option in that code sorry.

Comment: <option value="' + b[x].FirstName + ' ' + b[x].MiddleInitial + ' ' + b[x].LastName + '">' + b[x].FirstName + ' ' + b[x].MiddleInitial + ' ' + b[x].LastName + '</option>

Comment: and in the hidden input type the value of the username is in that

Answer (score 0):

use my example to solve your task:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <head>
    <body>
        <select>
            <option value="1" hidden-attr="hidden attr for 1">Option 1</option>
            <option value="2" hidden-attr="hidden attr for 2">Option 2</option>
            <option value="3" hidden-attr="hidden attr for 3">Option 3</option>
            <option value="4" hidden-attr="hidden attr for 4">Option 4</option>
            <option value="5" hidden-attr="hidden attr for 5">Option 5</option>
            <option value="6" hidden-attr="hidden attr for 6">Option 6</option>
        </select>
        <script>
                $("select").change(function(){
                    var val = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
                    var hidden = $(this).find("option:selected").attr("hidden-attr");
                    alert ("Value: " + val + ", hidden attribute:" + hidden);
                })
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of hidden field you add extra attribute like this and hold your extra value.

```js
 $('select').change(function(){
       var selected = $(this).find('option:selected');
       var imageSrc = selected.data('image'); 
       alert(imageSrc);
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select">
  <option value="1" data-image="image1">A</option>
  <option value="2" data-image="image2">B</option>
  <option value="3" data-image="image3">C</option>
</select>
```